# Splash screen doesn't have Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, plymouth

Ubuntu is working perfectly, but the splash screen looks similar to this:

[image]

I'm using 19.10. But I was facing similar issue with 18.04 and 19.04.

Output of `sudo update-alternatives --display default.plymouth`:

```
 link best version is /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
 link currently points to /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
 link default.plymouth is /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
 slave default.plymouth.grub is /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth - priority 110
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth - priority 70
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth - priority 100
 slave default.plymouth.grub: /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub
```

Comment: 19.10, but the LTS version and 19.04 were also like this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the output of `sudo update-alternatives --display default.plymouth`.

Comment: I did this procedure, restarted and it didn't work out the problem persists

Comment: post edited and included

Comment: Run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and you might get a list to choose the default splash screen. Choose the number that corresponds to something like `ubuntu_logo`

Comment: the problem continues

Comment: @RafaelDosSantos Are you using nvidia?

Comment: no, is AMD Radeon R5 230

Comment: [This is what works for Nvidia](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2016/03/plymouth-fix-nvidia.html). Not sure if it applies here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you need to use a framebuffer so that you have graphics when you boot up.

Run the following commands:

```
echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: also did not solve

Comment: The extra "echo" inside the quotes is causing FRAMEBUFFER=y to simply be displayed on screen at boot instead of applying the setting.  Edit has been submitted to correct this. On my Intel J1900 SoC processor this fixed the issue (with my fix to the command).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with **plymouth**.
My suggestion:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  plymouth-themes
```

and then.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I did this procedure and it didn't work

Comment: Is there some kind of error or warning message after sudo update-initramfs -u ?

Comment: did the procedures, restarted and still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of themes available via the repositories through [Synaptic package manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) or through the command line via `aptitude:`

```
$ aptitude search plymouth-theme
p   lubuntu-plymouth-theme        - plymouth theme for Lubuntu
p   plymouth-theme-fade-in        - graphical boot animation and logger - fade-in theme
p   plymouth-theme-glow           - graphical boot animation and logger - glow theme
i   plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo   - graphical boot animation and logger - kubuntu-logo theme
p   plymouth-theme-sabily         - plymouth theme for Sabily
p   plymouth-theme-script         - graphical boot animation and logger - script theme
p   plymouth-theme-solar          - graphical boot animation and logger - solar theme
p   plymouth-theme-spinfinity     - graphical boot animation and logger - spinfinity theme
p   plymouth-theme-text           - graphical boot animation and logger - text theme
c   plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo    - graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-logo theme
i   plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text    - graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-logo theme
p   plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio   - Ubuntu Studio Plymouth theme
p   xubuntu-plymouth-theme        - Plymouth theme for Xubuntu
```

You can then install the resulting packages via Synaptic or aptitude as normal:

In your case

```
$ sudo aptitude install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```