# Earth Sunrise plymouth theme

Tags: plymouth

Since upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 19.10, I can't get it to work.  What am I doing wrong? I have been using this Plymouth theme since 16.04 and really like it but since upgrading from 18.04 LTS, I can't get to to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've stopped using my own Earth Sunrise theme because with a fast SSD it only runs for a second. You can check this Q&A for similar problems in 19.10: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182485/splash-screen-doesnt-have-ubuntu-logo